# Issues running tensorflow on docker

Tags: docker, tensorflow, dockerfile

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM python:3.6

WORKDIR /Users/thakm004/Documents/

COPY requirements.txt ./
COPY handler.py ./
COPY 
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python", "handler.py" ]
```

Here is my requirements file;

```
tensorflow
tensorflow-hub
Pillow
matplotlib
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
2021-03-08 03:05:00.718684: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

2021-03-08 03:05:00.718753: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
```

It doesn't point to a section of my code but here is where tensorflow is called:

```
# Convert to float32 numpy array, add batch dimension, and normalize to range [0, 1]. Example using numpy:
content_image_processed = content_image.astype(np.float32)[np.newaxis, ...] / 255.
style_image_processed = style_image.astype(np.float32)[np.newaxis, ...] / 255.
# Optionally resize the images. It is recommended that the style image is about
# 256 pixels (this size was used when training the style transfer network).
# The content image can be any size.
style_image = tf.image.resize(style_image, (256, 256))

# Load image stylization module.
hub_module = hub.load('https://tfhub.dev/google/magenta/arbitrary-image-stylization-v1-256/2')

# Stylize image.
outputs = hub_module(tf.constant(content_image_processed[:,:,:,:3]), tf.constant(style_image_processed[:,:,:,:3]))
stylized_image = outputs[0]
```

Comment: Do you want to run this container with a GPU? If not, you can safely ignore those messages. They are only relevant when using a GPU.

Comment: Thats what I thought by my docker container "exits" when I try to run it.

Comment: Does your script save the output to a file? If so, you will want to mount a directory onto the container, so you can access the file after the container exits.